# How to Lock The Postgres SQL Table expliclty using Java using user transcation

Tags: java, postgresql, transactions

How to Lock The Postgres SQL Table explicitly using Java in user transaction mode

I have written one query to execute under user transaction:

```
LOCK TABLE tablename IN ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;
```

throws exception in java:

> LOCK TABLE can only be used in transaction blocks

Comment: you can write a postgres function which will lock the table for you for specific time after calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, then start a transaction by executing `COMMIT` or disabling autocommit mode in JDBC.

Note that explicit locking of tables is almost always the wrong solution, particularly if it happens often.